# How to structure a list with JSON objects in Python?

Tags: python, json

I got a list in Python with Twitter user information and exported it with Pandas to an Excel file.
One row is one Twitter user with nearly all information of the user (`name`, `@-tag`, `location` etc.)

Here is my code to create the list and fill it with the user data:

```
def get_usernames(userids, api):
    fullusers = []
    u_count = len(userids)
    try:
        for i in range(int(u_count/100) + 1):
            end_loc = min((i + 1) * 100, u_count)
            fullusers.extend(
                api.lookup_users(user_ids=userids[i * 100:end_loc])
            )
        print('\n' + 'Done! We found ' + str(len(fullusers)) + ' follower in total for this account.' + '\n')
        return fullusers

    except:
        import traceback
        traceback.print_exc()
        print ('Something went wrong, quitting...')
```

The only problem is that every row is in JSON object and therefore one long comma-seperated string. I would like to create headers (no problem with Pandas) and only write parts of the string (i.e. `ID` or `name`) to colums.

Here is an example of a row from my output.xlsx:

```
User(_api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0x16898928>, _json={'id': 12345, 'id_str': '12345', 'name': 'Jane Doe', 'screen_name': 'jdoe', 'location': 'Nirvana, NI', 'description': 'Just some random descrition')
```

I have two ideas, but I don't know how to realize them due to my lack of skills and experience with Python.

1. Create a loop which saves certain parts (`'id'`,`'name'` etc.) from the JSON-string in colums.
2. Cut off the `User(_api=<tweepy.api. API object at 0x16898928>, _json={` at the beginning and `)` at the end, so that I may export they file as CSV.

Could anyone help me out with one of my two solutions or suggest a "simple" way to do this?

fyi: I want to do this to gather data for my thesis.

Comment: When you initially get the json object, parse it with the `json.loads()` function from the `json` library. It will return a `dict`. Create a Pandas DataFrame from that, and use the columns you need, and export to excel from there. Docs on `json` library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Comment: I don't exactly know at which point I have to use `json.loads()`. I create a list (`fullusers = []`)and fill it with `extend(api.lookup_users()`
PS: I added the code to get the user in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try the python json library:

```
import json
jsonstring = "{'id': 12345, 'id_str': '12345', 'name': 'Jane Doe', 'screen_name': 'jdoe', 'location': 'Nirvana, NI', 'description': 'Just some random descrition')"

jsondict = json.loads(jsonstring)
# type(jsondict) == dictionary
```

Now you can just extract the data you want from it:

```
id = jsondict["id"]
name = jsondict["name"]
newdict = {"id":id,"name":name}
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I created the `jsonstring = fullusers[0]` (which contains the string mentioned in my question), but when I try to create the `jsondict` it told me that the JSON object is User.

Comment: In addition: I have a list with objects (returned from tweepy). `type(fullusers[0])` returns `<class 'tweepy.models.User'>`. So the problem seems to be that I have a kinda strange type which can't be serialized with `json.loads`

Comment: I found a solution:
I just added `fullusers = [x._json for x in fullusers]` at the end of my `get_usernames` function to just extract the _json part from the `<class 'tweepy.models.User'>`